# Run program in Python 2.7, not in Python 3.5

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, virtualenv

I'm setting up in connecting raspberry pi with LCD and found some problem.

I've tried to use both `sudo pip install adafruit-circuitpython-charlcd` and `sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-charlcd`. When I run the program, with `python filename.py` there is an error below, but when run the program with `python3.5 filename.py`, it's smoothly running, and I want to ask how can I run the program using Python, not in Python 3.5.

My code:

```py
import time
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD

# Raspberry Pi pin setup
rs = 26
en = 19
d4 = 13
d5 = 6
d6 = 5
d7 = 11
backlight = 2

# Define LCD column and row size for 16x2 LCD.
columns = 16
rows = 2

lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(rs,en,d4,d5,d6, d7,columns,rows,backlight)
lcd.message('Hlooo')
```

The error message, I get:

```
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
ImportError: No module named 'Adafruit_CharLCD'
```

Comment: Check the version of your `python` command. Usually, it is mapped to the Python 2 version installed, while `python3` is mapped to the Python 3 installation.

Comment: Try to install using: python -m pip install adafriut-circuitpython-charlcd

This will explicitly install into pip of python2. 

I would suggest you use something like conda to manage your python version.

Comment: I would suggest you use Python 3 for your projects since Python 2 will not be maintained past January 1, 2020. If you need to port some code from Python 2 to Python 3 here is how: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Comment: using python2,3, and 3.5, but my adafriut-circuitpython-charlcd located in 3.5, how can move the package to python2? already use pip uninstall and pip install to python2 but the location still in 3,5

Answer (score -1):

"Copy the Adafruit_CharLCD.py file (and any other files inside the same directory as it) to the same directory as your python script. Whenever Python sees an import statement (like "import Adafruit_CharLCD") it goes through a few paths to find the import file and the last option is to look in the directory of the currently running script."

Copied from @tdicola from github.

Answer (score -1):

- The best way of running your python program as per industry standards will be using a virtual environment and make sure you create the environment with the python version which is required for your program to run.
  Please follow the steps mentioned to create the virtual environment with specified version
  https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000695551-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-3

--> There is a small hack too if you want to run with current setup by providing the python alias in the .bashrc profile if working on linux.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: nhaah already used in virtualenv, but in my virtualenv doesn't support use opencv, can I ask you how to make virtualenv support opencv?

Comment: This might be compatibility issue as for python 3.6 if you want the program to run it supports cv2 you can try updating your module with supported version